# Overloading Function Templates for C-strings

Tags: c++, overloading, c-strings, function-templates

The following snippet code is an example from book c++ templates. My question is why the the statement return max (max(a,b), c) in the last line becomes a runtime error. Could anyone give me some hints? Thanks!

```
#include <cstring>
// maximum of two values of any type (call-by-reference)
template<typename T>
T const& max (T const& a, T const& b)
{
return b < a ? a : b;
}
// maximum of two C-strings (call-by-value)
char const* max (char const* a, char const* b)
{
return std::strcmp(b,a) < 0 ? a : b;
}
// maximum of three values of any type (call-by-reference)
template<typename T>
T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
return max (max(a,b), c); // error if max(a,b) uses call-by-value
}
int main ()
{
auto m1 = ::max(7, 42, 68); // OK
char const* s1 = "frederic";
char const* s2 = "anica";
char const* s3 = "lucas";
auto m2 = ::max(s1, s2, s3); // run-time ERROR
}
```

Comment: `warning: returning reference to local temporary object return max (max(...)`

Comment: could you please give more elaboration why max(a,b) creates a new, temporary local value that is returned by reference? Since char const* max (char const* a, char const* b) applies to max(a,b), where pointers are passed, how will the temporary local value be created?

Comment: `T const& max` returns a temporary const reference to a `const char *`. Pointers are also variables. Please indent your code.

Comment: You can specify the first parameter type with a variadic to avoid this https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6EEesMnW9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char const* max (char const* a, char const* b)` returns an `const char *` variable by value. Then `T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)` creates a temporary variable that stores that value and returns a `const&` reference to it (with `T = const char *`). That temporary pointer does not exist, when `auto m2 =` is assigned. Most probably, you print or inspect the value later, which causes some kind of "runtime error".

I guess, return a reference to `const char *` from the start.

```
char const * const& max (char const * const& a, char const * const& b) {
   return std::strcmp(b, a) < 0 ? a : b;
}
```